# MatrixGestureDetector only works if gesture is started horizontally and not vertically?

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix, gesture

I am using the `matrix_gesture_detector` package found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector/versions).

My problem is the package only seems to work if I'm interacting with it horizontally.

Here is the widget I've made as a wrapper around the default `MatrixGestureDetector`:

```dart
class Moveable extends StatelessWidget {
  Moveable({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onDragStart,
    required this.onDragEnd,
    required this.onDragUpdate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final Function(Offset offset) onDragStart;
  final Function(Offset offset) onDragEnd;
  final Function(Offset offset) onDragUpdate;

  final Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      child: MatrixGestureDetector(
        shouldTranslate: true,
        shouldScale: true,
        shouldRotate: true,
        onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) => notifier.value = m,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: notifier,
          builder: (ctx, _) {
            return Transform(
              transform: notifier.value,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It basically just manipulates a `child`'s transform based on matrix updates caused by common gestures (dragging fingers on the screen to translate, rotating fingers to rotate, and pinching to zoom (scale) in/out). This widget is meant to be placed inside a `Stack`.

It mostly works great — gestures on the `Moveable` can translate, rotate, and scale the `child`. HOWEVER, only gestures that are *started* horizontally. AKA, if I *start* scaling with my 2 fingers vertically it doesn't work (same with translating and rotating).

Everything works eventually if I start the action horizontally. AKA, if I start horizontally, I can *then* do vertical actions.

Can anybody help with this? I'm quite confused as to why this would be happening.

The source code for the `MatrixGestureDetector` can be found [here](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart) where it appears to not discriminate in any way between horizontal and vertical gestures.